# Resizing ImageIcon with its corners in Java

Tags: java, imageicon

I'm making a Unicode translator in Java. I done all hard part. But now I want to add an image to the TextPane and user must have the ability to resize image with its edges and drag & drop the image within the TextPane where he likes. (like Microsoft Word or Photoshop)

I tried the Styled Document properties.But I couldn't find way except insert only the imageicon.

Can anyone help me with this trouble?

Comment: What do you mean by "with its edges"? Could you draw a picture of what you want to happen? If you have something almost but not quite working, could you show a screenshot and highlight what's wrong with it?

Comment: Reposted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6288064/resizing-imageicon-with-its-corners-in-java

Answer (score 1):

May be a better choice would be not to use textPane.

If you have an custom editable label, that can be edited by double clicking on it to show a text box to edit the contents, and change the text of the label when enter key is pressed.

Also give a shot of JDesktoppane, JLayeredPane, and check what components can be added to it.