# how to make java run time sizable image box

Tags: java, imageicon

I'm making a Unicode translator in Java. I did all hard parts, but now I want to add a resizable, relocatable image to the textpane. The user must be able to resize image with its corners and drag & drop the image within the textpane where he likes. (like Microsoft Word or Photoshop)

Something like this:

[image: screen shot of desired resize handles]

I tried the Styled Document properties. But I couldn't find way except inserting only an `ImageIcon`.

Answer (score 1):

May be a better choice would be not to use textPane.

If you have an custom editable label, that can be edited by double clicking on it to show a text box to edit the contents, and change the text of the label when enter key is pressed.

Also give a shot of JDesktoppane, JLayeredPane, and check what components can be added to it.

Answer (score 1):

try this 
http://mgeisler.net/downloads/browser/src/ImageBox.java.html

Answer (score 0):

try loading the image inside a JLabel component in JFC Swing.
Otherwise try some other non editable components in the same technology with resizable property.

Answer (score 0):

try this http://sourceforge.net/projects/ird/
the iRD is a component for Resize and move(drag&drop) compoennts on runtime in java.